# How to add a button "on" the image at one corner of image?

Tags: css

I want to place **buttons On the Top of the image** in three places

1. Bottom Left Corner of the image
2. Bottom Right corner of the image
3. Center of the image. (optional)....

**How to place these button on the top of the image.**

```
<img src="images/default_image.png" style="width:90%" id="mImage"  />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery or jQuery mobile really. Can be done with simple HTML and CSS. See this fiddle for am example on how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/rHaPH/22/

Comment: in jsfiddle it works but in my code Buttons are displaye at the bottom of the immage in my code

Comment: But i used jQuery mobile what s'd i do

Comment: This is not a "get free code" site, this is questions and answers. Both me and @Dessus have demonstrated how to position elements on top of an image in the manner you want. You should try to apply those tips on your own problem and solve it (and learn something in the process), not ask us to do your work for you. :) Good luck.

Comment: As I see it, he is asking to place a jquery mobile button (data-role="button") on top of image. Maybe the question is not clear 100% but I had also the same question. I knew how to place a button or other element on top of an image or other divs but I wanted to implement that with jquery mobile components. So I add my answer to the question event thought is has been more than a year...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div id="div-1">
  <img src="../img/logo.png" style="width:90%" id="mImage">
  <div id="div-1a" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div-1b" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
#div-1 {
 position:relative;
}
#div-1a {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
#div-1b {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
}
```

You can copy that into JS fiddle and it will work using JQMobile. Make sure you include the css url for JQM and make sure you tick JQMobile when adding JQuery to your JS fiddle.

**Update:**

You should also beware that JQMobile will inject span tags into the DOM which will be your buttons at runtime. This means the css I have provided is conceptually ok, but the selectors will need to point to those span tags (as opposed to using the ids of div tags).

Comment: in this case also Buttons are displaye ata the bottom of the immage

Comment: yea, you can swap top:0 for bottom:0

Answer (score 0):

As today, with jQuery mobile v1.3.2 I have implemented that in the following way:

```
<div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="content">
      <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="button">
            <a href="#" data-role="button">Button</a>
         </div>
         <img src="i.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And with the follow css:

```
#wrapper{ position:relative; }
#button{ position:absolute; top: 10px; left:0px; z-index:10; }
img{max-width:100%; }
```

Some styles probably are not needed for what you want, but I just took the code sample from my own code.

wrapper div is relative positioned so its contents can be absolutely positioned.

z-index in the button div is to make sure it is placed on top of image.

You can add as many buttons as desired and change its css properties for top, left, right and button to move them around the image

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7QuH/)